# Random String Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller I am trying to generate a random string from my **function run_key()** I have tried it but not generating random string. It works if I do it like this example

```
public function index () {
  $this->load->helper('string');
  // Currently Hard Coded Key
  $data['encryption_key'] = random_string(&^)(*&sf465sd4fsd6^%1321^%#, 128);

  //Also Tried
  $data['encryption_key'] = random_string($this->run_key(), 128);
  $data['encryption_key'] = random_string($len, 128);
}
```

I am trying to get it so can generate a random string from my **function run key()** Not working.

On The Same Controller

```
public function run_key() {

$chars = array(
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '?', '!', '@', '#',
'$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', ';', '/', '=', '+'
);

shuffle($chars);

$num_chars = count($chars) - 1;
$token = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
$token .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $num_chars)];
}

return $token;
}
}
```

Comment: in your `for` loop, `$len` is undeclared. maybe you mean `$num_chars` to in that place instead of `$len`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, your are using the function helper [`random_string()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html) wrong.

Sample Usage:

> **`echo random_string('alnum', 16);`**
>
> *The first parameter specifies the type of string, the second parameter specifies the length. The following choices are available:* **`alpha, alunum, numeric, nozero, unique, md5, encrypt and sha1`**

Since you're rolling your own random string. You really dont need to do this.

Second, in your for loop, `$len` is undeclared. Maybe you mean `$num_chars` in that place instead of `$len`.

```
public function run_key() {

    $chars = array(
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '?', '!', '@', '#',
        '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', ';', '/', '=', '+'
    );

    shuffle($chars);

    $num_chars = count($chars) - 1;
    $token = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_chars; $i++){ // <-- $num_chars instead of $len
        $token .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $num_chars)];
    }

    return $token;
}
```

Comment: I have done it by the user guide, but run key not work. I will have to use what you recommend alpha, alunum, numeric, nozero, unique, md5, encrypt and sha1 rather than extra script I think.

Comment: @acoderslife what do you mean _not work_?. heres that sample of the code http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kltf6C

Comment: When I added it to this  $data['encryption_key'] = ""; on my function index. This way works $data['encryption_key'] = random_string('alpha', 128); But not sure what to do to add run key function to the $data['encryption_key']

Comment: `$data['encryption_key'] = $this->run_key();`

Comment: Got it now. Can you sent max numbers to like 32 near where mt rand is is it

Comment: either use a function `substr($this->run_key(), 0, 31)` or instead of `$num_chars` on the loop, set it to `31`